# Ruby on Rails - gem Rack issue on production - warning: already initialized constant Rack::Utils::STATUS_WITH_NO_ENTITY_BODY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, digital-ocean, rack, unicorn

I've a site in Ruby on Rails hosted on DigitalOcean using **mina deploy** to deployment. I get deploy my application, but when I accessing my droplet by IP on Browser, I get the error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

I checked the unicorn log and it shows this:

```
root@marconportfa2018:~# tail -f /var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log
/home/nrt/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:547: warning: already initialized constant Rack::Utils::STATUS_WITH_NO_ENTITY_BODY
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:547: warning: previous definition of STATUS_WITH_NO_ENTITY_BODY was here
/home/nrt/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:549: warning: already initialized constant Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:549: warning: previous definition of SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE was here
/home/nrt/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:562: warning: already initialized constant Rack::Utils::Multipart
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:562: warning: previous definition of Multipart was here
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
I, [2018-04-16T20:53:27.589122 #26924]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2018-04-16T20:53:27.590074 #26922]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

And I checked the nginx error.log to:

```
root@marconportfa2018:/var/log/nginx# tail -f error.log
2018/04/16 07:09:26 [crit] 1226#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 177.183.110.26, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock:/", host: "159.65.75.62"
```

.ruby-version

```
2.1.3@marconPortfa
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: We need more information. The unicorn logs are showing warnings, not errors. If you're using Rails then you should have `log/production.log` (or `log/development.log` or whatever the name of the environment is that you're running Rails in), and THAT is the log we need to see.

Comment: @anothermh I'm running production environment. My production.log don't has any info, is blank. I updated the Question with nginx error log (error.log). Can you please check it out to? Maybe this can help. Thanks!

Comment: Post your unicorn configuration file.